# How do I return to the Beginning of my Program without a Goto Statement

Tags: c, function, loops, break

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

long factcalc(int num1);

int main(void) 
{
    int num1;
    long factorial;
    int d;
    int out;

    printf("Please enter a number that is greater than 0");
    scanf_s("%d", &num1);

    if (num1 < 0) {
        printf("Error, number has to be greater than 0");
    } else if (num1 == 0) {
        printf("\nThe answer is 1");
    } else {
        factorial = factcalc(num1);
        printf("\nThe factorial of your number is\t %ld", factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}

long factcalc(int num1) 
{
    int factorial = 1;
    int c;

    for (c = 1; c <= num1; c++)
    factorial = factorial * c;

    return factorial;
}
```

I was wondering, how do I make it so that the program keeps asking the user for input until the user inputs '-1'? So that even after it has calculated the factorial of one number it keeps asking for more numbers until -1 is put in by the user, same goes for when it displays the error message and such. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not to use a loop ? I don't think there is need of `goto` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be easily achieved by introducing an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define scanf_s scanf
#endif

long factcalc(int num1);

int main(void)
{
    int num1;
    long factorial;
    int d;
    int out;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Please enter a number that is greater than 0");
        scanf_s("%d", &num1);
        if (num1 == -1) {

            break;
        }

        else if (num1 < 0) {

            printf("Error, number has to be greater than 0");
        }

        else if (num1 == 0) {

            printf("\nThe answer is 1");
        }

        else {

            factorial = factcalc(num1);
            printf("\nThe factorial of your number is\t %ld", factorial);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

long factcalc(int num1) {

    int factorial = 1;
    int c;

    for (c = 1; c <= num1; c++)
        factorial = factorial * c;

    return factorial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a select few scenarios where using `goto` is "okay," but this is surely not one.

First, put the relevant bits of your program into functions.

Then, monitor and use the user input like so:

```
int number = -1;

while (scanf("%d", &number)) {
    if (-1 == number) {
        break;
    }

    call_foo_function(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as suggested by @ameyCU, using loop is solution. For example,

```
while (1)
{
    printf("Please enter a number that is greater than 0");
    scanf_s("%d", &num1);

    if (-1 == num1)
    {
        break;
    }

    // Find factorial of input number
    ...
    ...

    // Loop back to get next input from user
}
```